# How to get data on how fast the wake word detection on Amazon Alexa/Google Home is?

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, alexa-voice-service, google-home

I am building a wake word(ww) detector using Tensorflow's Simple audio recognition tutorial. The model generated takes approximately 5 seconds to detect if the input audio file is a wake word or not. It has to be sped up.

I want to know if there is any way to obtain metrics/data on how long Alexa/Google Home take to detect their ww. There doesn't seem to be any documentation as such out there. Does anyone have this measure already so that I know how much more faster my own detector can perform?